# GMailSender works on one phone but not on another

Tags: android

I implemented an application which sends emails via GmailSender. In my phone (2.2.1) it works perfectly. However, in another (4.2.1) it does not send any email without giving any error. 
What could be the reason?

Comment: send email by calling an `Intent` instead of using `GmailSender`.it will work on every phone..

Comment: Can I use intents without user interaction?

Comment: nope..user will at least have to click the **Send** button..